# Combine multiple rows by group, and list keep the first value in each column that isn't NA, in R

Tags: r

My data.frame looks like

```
ID  Encounter  Value1  Value2
1      A         1       NA
1      A         2       10
1      B         NA      20
1      B         4       30
2      A         5       40
2      A         6       50
2      B         NA      NA
2      B         7       60
```

and I want it to look like

```
ID    Encounter  Value1  Value2
1        A        1       10
1        B        4       20       
2        A        5       40
2        B        7       60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`.  Grouped by 'ID', 'Encounter', get the `first` value that is not an `NA` (`!is.na(.)`) in the rest of the column.  By any chane, if all the values are NA, then return the `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID, Encounter) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA_integer_ 
           else first(.[!is.na(.)]))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
#     ID Encounter Value1 Value2
#  <int> <chr>      <int>  <int>
#1     1 A              1     10
#2     1 B              4     20
#3     2 A              5     40
#4     2 B              7     60
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
Encounter = c("A", 
"A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B"), Value1 = c(1L, 2L, NA, 4L, 
5L, 6L, NA, 7L), Value2 = c(NA, 10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, NA, 
60L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```